# I'm unable to update the entered data into db

Tags: php, mysqli

Here is my code

```
  <?php
  include('admin/class.php');
```

This is the db connection

```
  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "timesheet1234");
```

here am giving action to my save button

```
if(isset($_POST['save']))
{  
  $sel=@$_POST['selpro'];
  $mon=@$_POST['mon'];
  $tue=@$_POST['tue'];
  $wed=@$_POST['wed'];
  $thu=@$_POST['thu'];
  $fri=@$_POST['fri'];
  $sat=@$_POST['sat'];
  $sun=@$_POST['sun'];
```

This is where the problem occurs

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    echo "session user";
```

It is not accepting the `mysqli`

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link,"UPDATE empdaytimesheet SET 
`projectcode`='$sel',`mon`='$mon',`tue`='$tue',`wed`='$wed',
`thu`='$thu',`fri`='$fri',`sat`='$sat',`sun`='$sun' where
`username`='".$_SESSION['user']."'");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"siiiiiii", $sel,$mon,$tue,$wed,$thu,$fri,$sat,$sun);

$res= mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

It is not coming to this condition

```
if($res){
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
  echo "alert('TimeSheet Saved..!')";
  echo "</script>";
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
  echo "window.location='my_timesheet.php'";
  echo "</script>";
}
```

Instead it executes this:

```
else {
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
  echo "alert('Some Error Occured ! Retry..!')";
  echo "</script>";
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
  echo "window.location='my_timesheet.php'";
  echo "</script>";
}
}
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: Do you have any errors on screen or in the error log?

Comment: Can you `var_dump($res)` and print your output to here? So that we all can see.

Comment: use `?` instead of `$sel`,  in `prepare()` statement

Comment: MYSQLI_BIND_PARAM EXPECTS ONE PARAMETER IS THE WARNING AM GETTING...

Comment: OK. I WILL TRY USING IT...@DIeCHO

Comment: -1 at glance for all the @'s

Comment: You do not pass variables in prepare statements...try `mysqli_prepare($link,"UPDATE empdaytimesheet SET 
  projectcode = ?,mon= ?,tue=?,wed= ?,
  thu= ?,fri= ?,sat=?,sun=? where
  username='".$_SESSION['user']."'")` .. where you want to bind the variable. put `?`

Answer (score 0):

TRY ( use placeholder `(?)` instead of direct variables )

```
$stmt = "UPDATE empdaytimesheet SET `projectcode`=?,
                                    `mon`=?,
                                    `tue`=?,
                                    `wed`=?,
                                    `thu`=?,
                                    `fri`=?,
                                    `sat`=?,
                                    `sun`=? 
        WHERE username = ?";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $stmt);
// s : corresponding variable has type string
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssssssss', $sel, $mon, $tue, $wed,$thu,$fri,$sat,$sun,$username);

$sel = 'whatevr';
$mon = 'whatever';
//...
//...so on ...

$stmt->execute();
```

[Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: BUT I HAVE TO ENTER THE DATA IN WEBPAGE AND THE DATA GIVEN IN THIS PAGE SHUD BE UPDATED IN DB...

Comment: Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to      be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mounika  iddle1.php on line 47

Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mounika/middle1.php on line 54

Comment: when am using the above code am getting above warning and error...

Comment: Please read the reference manual...

Comment: which reference manual..

Comment: see the bottom of my answer

Comment: k but when am using mysql i did't got all this warnings r errors and the problem with mysql is it is not updating the databut in this stackoverflow one suggested me to use mysqli now completely it is not working....

Answer (score 0):

Your way of using prepared statements is wrong.

You have to use *placeholders* instead of variables:

Also you are not checking for errors and thus you're unable ho get a hint from a database

```
$sql  = "UPDATE empdaytimesheet SET `projectcode`=?',`mon`=? ..."; // and so on
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($link));
```

note the second line. it will raise a PHP error which will tell you what's going wrong

Answer (score -1):

Binding the statements in general means that you are putting the variable in place where you left placeholder `?`
You never place actual variables when preparing the statements.

```
$stmt = "UPDATE empdaytimesheet SET `projectcode`=?,
                                `mon`=?,
                                `tue`=?,
                                `wed`=?,
                                `thu`=?,
                                `fri`=?,
                                `sat`=?,
                                `sun`=? 
    WHERE username = ?";
```

when you write the above statement you are actually the indicating to  mysql that you are going to execute query of this form ...

and when you bind the query using

```
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssssssss', $sel, $mon, $tue,    $wed,$thu,$fri,$sat,$sun,$username);
```

you are giving the actual values to be replaced instead on `?`

Reason why you are getting the error is because your statement is not getting prepare properly and so `mysqli_prepare` is returning `false`

try catching the error there using `mysqli_prepare() or die(mysqli_error())`

see more [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)